# Process in which new nodes are added to a linked list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, allocation

I know how the program works but i can't wrap my head around the concenpt. Here is the main function:

```
void main() {
lista node1, p, q;
int n, i;
int a;

node1 = NULL;
printf("data = ");
scanf("%d", &a);
while (!feof(stdin)) {
    if (add_to_list(&node1, a)!=0) {
        printf("nod (CTRL-z) = ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
    }
    else printf("can't insert");
}
```

And here is the add_to_list function

```
int add_to_list(lista *head, int info) { 
lista p, nou;
int cod;
if (nou = (lista)malloc(sizeof(nod))) { 
    if (*head == NULL) {
        nou->data = info;
        nou->leg = NULL;
        *head = nou; //la adresa listei noastre in primul element se baga noul element creat aici
    }
    else {
        p = *head;
        while (p->leg != NULL) {
            p = p->leg;
        }
        nou->data = info;
        nou->leg = NULL;
        p->leg = nou;
    }
cod = 1;
}
else {
    cod = 0;
}
return cod;
}
```

And this is the data structure i'm using

```
typedef struct nod {
int data;
struct nod *leg;
} *lista;
```

So the problem is, although i fully understand what happens in the whole program, I can't understand how are nodes continually added.

If you look in the main() function i have node1 set to NULL, then i get the .data (held in int a) for each 'node'. The add_to_list function is called passing the address of node1 and the digit, right? In the function it allocates space since it's null, puts the value of variable a in the .data field then asigns NULL to this node's pointer (it's asumes it might be the last one so it's the right thing to do). Clear until now.

Now returning 'cod 1' to the main function() it means i'm allowed to further input numbers from my keyboard. The thing is, let's say I input the digit '3', again function add_to_list is called passing a null node1 and '3' (var a). After this i don't get it.

my ideea is that node1 is no longer null since it was passed as a 'reference' and it contains the address of the first node. So in the add_to_list() it should jump straight to else part, try to find a node which points to null (the last one) and from there create a new one and connect it to the last one. Am i right? Or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: `feof` probably doesn't work like you think it does.  And you don't have to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right: the `else` part works for each node except the first one. And the `node1` parameter is modified only once when the first node is added into an [empty] list.

Answer (score 0):

The first time add_to_list() is called the head is NULL so the head is assigned to a new node with the right data. After that it isn't NULL so it will execute the else portion, which goes to the very end of the list then puts the newly created node at the end. If it returns 0 then there was an issue with malloc and that data wasn't inserted. Otherwise it was good. feof() will return 0 as long as you haven't hit the "end" of stdin and this allows you to continue inserting data.

Answer (score 0):

Your function to create node will return NULL only if malloc fails, of if the whole list is null. 
in the create node function you are rotation through the whole list to find the end node (that will point to NULL), and insert newly created node there